# set email confirmation to 'not confirmed' programmatically in magneto

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

How i can change email confirmation from 'confirmed' to 'not confirmed' programmatically in magneto.i have tried the below code,but it is not working

```
$customer->setConfirmation($customer->getRandomConfirmationKey());
$customer->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

//Try with below code.

```
$customer->setConfirmation(null);
$customer->save();
```

Or

```
$customer->setConfirmation(false);
$customer->save();
```